# Using global variables?

Tags: android, variables, global-variables

I am trying to use a global variable that will call in the current date. I have got the date going on a button click but I need to use the date for a calculation hence why I'm turning it into a global variable. I have tried a method and it isn't reading the date, the app crashes. If anyone could help it would be greatly appreciated

Global Class -

```
public class GlobalClass extends Application{

private Date date;

public Date getDate(){
    return date;
}
public void setDate(Date DDate){
    date = DDate;
}
```

CreateLine.Java (main java class, where I am trying to call the global variables -

```
public class CreateLine extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.create_line);
    myDb = new DatabaseHelper(this);


    GlobalClass globalVariable = (GlobalClass) getApplicationContext();
    globalVariable.setShippers20(28);
    final int shippers20 = globalVariable.setShippers20();

    GlobalClass globalVariable1 = (GlobalClass) getApplicationContext();
    globalVariable1.setShippers30(27);
    final int shippers30 = globalVariable.setShippers30();

    GlobalClass globalVariable2 = (GlobalClass) getApplicationContext();
    globalVariable2.setShippers20(10);
    final int time10 = globalVariable.setTime10();

    GlobalClass globalVariable3 = (GlobalClass) getApplicationContext();
    globalVariable3.getDate();
    Date Date = globalVariable3.getDate()

        }

    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yy/MM/dd HH:mm");
    datedisplay.setText(dateFormat.format(Date));
}
```

STACKTRACE

> 10-30 14:22:51.010 13812-13812/com.almac.tracker E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                      Process: com.almac.tracker, PID: 13812
>                                                                      java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.almac.tracker/com.almac.tracker.CreateLine}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'long java.util.Date.getTime()' on a null object reference
>                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2817)
>                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
>                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
>                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593)
>                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
>                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
>                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6540)
>                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
>                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
>                                                                       Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'long java.util.Date.getTime()' on a null object reference
>                                                                          at java.util.Calendar.setTime(Calendar.java:1749)
>                                                                          at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.format(SimpleDateFormat.java:981)
>                                                                          at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.format(SimpleDateFormat.java:974)
>                                                                          at java.text.DateFormat.format(DateFormat.java:341)
>                                                                          at com.almac.tracker.CreateLine.onCreate(CreateLine.java:343)
>                                                                          at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6980)
>                                                                          at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1213)
>                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2770)
>                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892) 
>                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
>                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593) 
>                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
>                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
>                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6540) 
>                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
>                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767) 
>   10-30 14:22:51.084 13812-13817/com.almac.tracker I/zygote: Do full code cache collection, code=105KB, data=79KB
>   10-30 14:22:51.085 13812-13817/com.almac.tracker I/zygote: After code cache collection, code=74KB, data=42KB

Comment: If it crashes, post the stack trace.

Comment: By the way, the troublesome old `Date` class has been supplanted by the `java.time.Instant` class. For earlier Android, see the *ThreeTen-Backport* and *ThreeTenABP* projects.

Answer (score 0):

First you are trying to get the date without setting it first. Consider calling the method `setDate` and set the date before using it. Or initialize it during declaration as

```
private Date date = new Date();
```

Next, I don't think you should not rely on the `getApplicationContext()` method.

If you want to use global variables accessible from all classes, use static fields.

```
public class GlobalClass {
    private static Date date = new Date();
    public static Date getDate(){
        return date;
    }
    public static void setDate( Date DDate ){
        date = DDate;
    }
}
```

Then you can set or get the date from any class using `GlobalClass.setDate()` or `GlobalClaas.getDate()`

Comment: Nabin, I'm only new to android so I'm not sure what you mean

Comment: Using `private Date date = new Date ();` in your `GlobalClass` should fix the problem.

Comment: instead of " private static Date date; "

Comment: changed the top line Nabin, and its still crashing

Comment: With the same error? If that doesn't work, try the code I posted.

Comment: tried your code too, unfortunately still not working

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there!
Just keep your Application class overload with a slight change:

```
public class GlobalClass extends Application{

    private Date date;

    public Date getDate(){
        return date == null ? new Date() : this.date;
    }
    public void setDate(Date DDate){
        this.date = DDate;
    }
}
```

Now to use it you need to do this inside your Activity:

```
public class CreateLine extends AppCompatActivity {

    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yy/MM/dd HH:mm");

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.create_line);

        myDb = new DatabaseHelper(this);


        // set date in your global variable
        ((GlobalClass) getApplication()).setDate(new Date());

        // get date value previously set
        Date mDate = ((GlobalClass) getApplicatio()).getDate();

        datedisplay.setText(dateFormat.format(mDate));

    }           

}
```

This may work for you.

Just a few **reminders**:

1 - Your overriding your Application class, you need to cast it everytime you need to set or get date.
2 - when outside of your Activities classes (if more than one) you need to have a context so you can get the Application object and then get or set the Date value: `((GlobalClass) ((Activity) mContext).getApplication()).getDate()`, where mContext is an Activity and you also need to cast it to Activity type.

Hope this helps. Cheers

Comment: Thank you, going to try this now :)

Comment: alexscmar thank you very much it doesn't crash no more!! thank you

Comment: So you can mark it as the correct answer :D.
You're welcome!

Comment: yea! how do I do that?

Comment: Check if this helps:
https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23138/how-to-accept-the-answer-on-stack-overflow